# Immediately hide div in Android WebView instead of after loading webpage

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a div called `downloadapp` that I'd like to display to users who visit my mobile website instead of using my Android app. So I need to hide that div for users who already use my app.

**My code:**

```
private void startWebView(String url) {
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      

    //On error, open local file
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none'; void(0);");
    }   

});

webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

**Problem:**

With the above code, the div `downloadapp`is being displayed for a few seconds (*until the whole page is finished loading*). At that moment, it disappears. What I want is that it's hidden immediately, so that people who use my app never see that div. How can i do that?

**EDIT:**

I tried to add `onPageStarted` but that doesn't work either.

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none'; void(0);");
}
```

Comment: Give a try with `onPageStarted`  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted

Comment: Why dont u just send a parameter with the url telling your server that it is your app who is visiting and not echo it to the user? that would a proper way to do it!

Comment: Yes, the right way is to send GET or POST parameter to server, when hitting web page url from mobile application. And then use server side code to remove `div`

Comment: Its late but use onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below hope it helps!!!

```
       @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var h1 = document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            view    .loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var h1 = document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");

        }
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding some explanation on how your code solves the problem at hand. Elaborated answers are better than sheer code.